# Django and thread safety

Tags: python, django, thread-safety

If I read the django documentation, only the documents about the template tags mention the potential danger of thread safety.

However, I'm curious what kind of things I have to do / avoid to write thread-safe code in Django...

One example is, I have the following function to config the loggers used in django.

```
_LOGGER_CONFIGURED = False

def config_logger():
    global _LOGGER_CONFIGURED
    if _LOGGER_CONFIGURED: return
    _LOGGER_CONFIGURED = True

    rootlogger = logging.getLogger('')
    stderr_handler = StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
    rootlogger.addHandler(stderr_handler)
```

and at the end of my root urlconf, i have the following function call:

```
config_logger()
```

The question is:

1. Is this code threadsafe?
2. What kind of variables are shared between the django threads?

Comment: You mean the potential danger of thread unsafety :p

Comment: I think there are potential places for thread-unsafety (some of them are pointed by people).

-urlresolver uses globally mutable dictionary, and this object can be put into indeterminiate state if concurrent requests occur when the server is starting.
-many django form and field classes have global counters... i don't know how they're used, but it doesn't seem like access to them aren't protected by mutexes. i guess that can be potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a whole lot you can do about django templates and their issues with threading, besides not using them, or at least not using the tags that are sensitive to threading issues.  There aren't many django template tags that do have issues, only the stateful ones do, such as `cycle`.

In the example you have given, you are not doing anything about thread safety, and you shouldn't be anyway: the `logging` module is already perfectly thread safe, so long as you use it in the normal way, which is to call `logging.getLogger` in the modules that need it, and `LOGGING` or `LOGGING_CONFIG` is [set appropriately](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) in your `settings.py`.  No need to be clever with this.

other things you might be concerned about are database integrity in the face of concurrent updates.  Don't be, if you are using PostgreSQL or MySQL/INNOdb databases, then you are completely protected from concurrency shennanegans.

Comment: i was aware of LOGGING and LOGGING_CONFIG, but i'm using django 1.2.3.

Comment: I guess the question is : I don't know what are global variables, and what are not global variables in django... only thing that appears obvious to me is the `request` variable in the request handlers. However, if you just have variable inside views.py, is this global among all the threads?

Comment: This comment seems a little broad brush: "Other things you might be concerned about are database integrity. [...] Don't be."  Sure, the hosting DBMS may handle all the concurrency issues, but I'm using PyODBC as my Django database access, and PyODBC expressly states you can use the same module from many threads, but NOT the same "connection" object.  Short of lunking around the Django code, can anyone tell me if Django correctly handles this -- and similar -- DB issues?

Comment: @Dan H: [I don't mind lunking around in the django code base](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/backends/__init__.py#L123)  In general, database connections are not thread-safe for most database clients.

Comment: I wouldn't say that you are "completely protected from concurrency" with MySQL.  Every now and then you need to use [select for update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) .  For example, if you have a counter that is incremented by a view that could be triggered in parallel.